# Concatenating data into an existing map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello I have the following code that maps through my text and prints typography,

```
{['Example1:', 'Example2:',].map(x => (
     <Typography key={x} className = { classes.titleText } variant="subtitle1" >{x}</Typography>
```

however, I want to concatenate my data into this map, the below example works but its very inefficient as i would need to copy and pasta every line and call each data set separately.

```
<Typography className = { classes.titleText } variant="subtitle1" >Example1 Date: {data.date} </Typography>
```

how can i call {data.date} within my original map? I have tried {['Example1' + {data.date} ]} but this does not work

Comment: Please don't repeat the same question in quick succession. Possible duplicate of [Calling data into map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298162/calling-data-into-map-function)

Comment: why do you duplicate your own question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of objects:

```
[{label: 'Example1:', date: someDate},{label: 'Example2:', date: someOtherdate}].map(x =>
     <Typography key={x.label} className = { classes.titleText } variant="subtitle1" >{x.date}</Typography>
```

The tricky thing will be to add the dates to the labels. You might need a mapping function like this:

```
const mergeDates = (data, labels) => labels.map(label => ({label, date: data[someindex].date}) )
```